# Reshape polygon to boundary of other polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have two polygons.

The first one has a white background and brown boundary.
To other has the pink background.

In QGIS, how is it possible to reshape to first polygon to the boundary of the other polygon?

[image]

Comment: Wich GIS system are you working with ?

Comment: @LaurentRobitaille-Lainesse - Already tagged =). Although a version number could also be useful.

Comment: may be this can help you http://anitagraser.com/2016/03/06/better-digitizing-with-qgis-2-14/

Comment: the last version of Qgis

Comment: Yeah trace digitize with the reshape feature tool.

Comment: Is this the only polygon you want to reshape, or are there many polygon to  process? What about the small polygon in the lower right part? Digitizing once again, is always an option, but hopefully the last one. My first idea: copy the boundary of that *pink* polygon, which contains the centroid of the brown one. In interactive mode you can try the experimental plugin *Geometry copier*, or use Python to automate this, if all requirements are known.

Answer (score -1):

PostGIS has ST_Snap, which could do most of what you need. I'm not current enough with QGIS though, so perhaps you can't use that through Processing, but would have to manually convert it to a database first and then load it through the DB manager.

However, do note that even ST_Snap is not completely deterministic, as it uses a heuristic, so sometimes the results won't be what you wanted.

Answer (score -2):

In ArcGIS toolbox one option is there search SNAP in Arc Toolbox. May be that is useful to you please check.

[image]

Comment: This Option available in ArcGIS

Comment: niels is using the latest version of Qgis. Tools from ArcGIS toolbox are not very useful in this case, except you want to design a new function running in Qgis.